# I cannot make changes to members in a class

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I'm having an issue with C# and XNA for Windows phone. I've created a class called Item which is inside of the Game1 class in XNA. The problem I am experiencing is that after I create all of the items I cannot make changes to them, it does not throw an error but also the change does not take effect. So the code goes something like this:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game {
  Item Loading;
  Item[] Stuff = new Item[2];

  public class Item {
    public bool visible = true;
  }

  protected override void LoadContent() {
    Loading = new Item();
    Stuff[1] = new Item();
  }

  protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime) {
    Loading.visible = false;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Loading.visible); //prints true
    Stuff[1].visible = false;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Stuff[1].visible); //prints false
  }
}
```

I don't understand why it is unable to change the variable, I have also tried doing this through an accessor method inside the class. I have basically duplicated code working for an array of Items, so that leaves me totally stumped.

Comment: can you show us the accessor method in the `Item` class?

Comment: What do you mean by "variable"? In OOP, we avoid the term "variable", we say "members" to refer to things that belong to classes, and some special memebr types are Methods (functions) and Properties. Yo cannot access "Loading" and "Stuff" from outside the class because by default members are private to the class. If you want to get values from Loading and Stuff, you should either declare them public (bad approach) or create public (may be read-only) properties (accessors) to the members.

Comment: @Y.Ecarri The `Update` method is part of the `Game1` class so it has access to the private members `Loading` and `Stuff[]`. That is not the issue here.

Comment: @JustinSkiles You are right. I missunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works. I removed the inheritance constraints but it should work with them too. The main issue I saw was the way you declared "Stuff". I am not sure what version of c# you are using but as far as I know (VS2010) you can't declare an array the way you did (as in C/C++). You must initialize the array with the `new` keyword.

```
public class Game1
{
    Item Loading;
    Item[] Stuff;

    public class Item
    {
        public bool visible = true;
    }

    public void LoadContent()
    {
        Loading = new Item();
        Stuff = new Item[2];
        Stuff[1] = new Item();
    }

    public void Update(DateTime gameTime)
    {
        Loading.visible = false;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Loading.visible); //prints false

        Stuff[1].visible = false;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Stuff[1].visible); //prints false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I mistyped my code, it was not a verbatim copy. I finally figured out the error, it was a 'me' error :-\ I managed to have two competing boolean switches and didn't notice it flipping back and forth.